# Customizing the images on menu items in QuadCurveMenu

Tags: ios

I am trying to customize the images of the menu items in quadcurve menu https://github.com/burtlo/QuadCurveMenu
I cant seem to figure out to give individual images to the various menu items.
Anyone who has had some experience with this ?

Answer (score 0):

in `QuadCurveDefaultMenuItemFactory`.h class `defaultMenuItemFactory`  method you can change the menu item images images.

Comment: you can change the image , but the same image is being used for all the menu items...can you elaborate a bit on how to customize the individual images for menu items ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set both the MainMenuItemFactory and the MenuItemFactory like this:

```
[menu setMainMenuItemFactory:mainMenuFactory];
[menu setMenuItemFactory:menuItemFactory];
```

If you use the same factory for both, the main menu item has a nil dataObject.